# running pid node from roslaunch, process dies

Tags: ros, pid, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried running the controller node from pid package
http://wiki.ros.org/pid

running from command line with rosrun works fine. but
using launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="linear_controller" pkg="pid" type="controller"
   args="1 6 .001 2000 -tfc lin_effort -tfp lin_state -fc 1000"/>
</launch>
```

getting error

```
    process[linear_controller-3]: started with pid [28035]
*** stack smashing detected ***: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/pid/controller terminated
[linear_controller-3] process has died [pid 28035, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/pid/controller 1 6 .001 2000 -tfc lin_effort -tfp lin_state -fc 1000 __name:=linear_controller __log:=/home/muaz/.ros/log/c6a3233e-3216-11e5-a8c9-20689d31db97/linear_controller-3.log].
log file: /home/muaz/.ros/log/c6a3233e-3216-11e5-a8c9-20689d31db97/linear_controller-3*.log
```

why it is getting stack smashing and exit code -6?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214509/running-pid-node-from-roslaunch,-process-dies/) by [radzaeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/23340/radzaeem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I think this thread has the answer. Roslaunch is adding additional arguments, which screws up the pid node. It expects a particular order for the first 4 arguments.

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/passing-arguments-to-an-executable-with-roslaunch-td1005764.html

I'm not sure what the workaround is yet. Perhaps I could re-release the package so the command is:

$ rosrun pid controller -Kp 2 -Ki 0.1 -Kd 0.05 -rate 200

It sucks to make the command even longer, though...

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2015-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-26**:
A ROS node should be able to handle these args properly. See [ros::removeROSArgs(..)](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/init_8h.html).

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2015-07-26**:
Alright, that worked. Thanks. I'm pushing new versions of the package to ROS (takes ~1 month), or you can get it directly from my repo in the meantime. There's a launch file with the package now.
https://bitbucket.org/AndyZe/pid/src/ab80beaa7e265213c4dfb37e7b99870c2cc84b41?at=master

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-26**:
I think if you called `check_user_input(..)` *after* `ros::init(argc, argv, node_name)`, the 'additional arguments' should already have been parsed and removed by ROS. Are things like remapping still working correctly the way you set things up?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2015-07-26**:
Yes, remapping appears to work. It might have been easier to put `check_user_input(..)` after `ros::init(argc, argv, node_name)`, but I'm not sure how that would affect node_name (since the node name needs to be parsed).